# XCode Swift: View Controller Navigation Area does not display correctly?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm new to XCode. Recently, I've been trying to create a Tab Bar Controller to connect 2 Table View Controllers. One of the Table View Controllers has a Search Bar on it.

I have tried to do this to create the Tab Bar Controller between the 2 Table View Controllers:

**This is how I tried to create the Tab Bar Controller**

[image: This is how I tried to create the Tab Bar Controller]

However, the app will simply crash when it opens. So instead, I amended the main storyboard by adding a Navigation Controller before the Tab Bar Controller:

**This is how I have amended the main storyboard so the app runs without crashing**

[image: This is how I have amended the main storyboard so the app runs without crashing]

Although the app runs without crashing, the problem I now have is that the Navigation Areas for the Table View Controllers are not displaying correctly:

**This is how the Table View Controller's Navigation Area is incorrectly displayed while running the app**

[image: This is how the Table View Controller's Navigation Area is incorrectly displayed while running the app]

Before I added the Tab Bar Controller, it was supposed to looked like this:

**This is how the Table View Controller's Navigation Area is supposed to look like**

[image: This is how the Table View Controller's Navigation Area is supposed to look like]

I'm thinking that it has something to do with adding the extra Navigation Controller before the Tab Bar Controller. Maybe this has caused a problem since there are now 2 Navigation Controllers connected to 1 Table View Controller?

Could someone please download the sample project from this website at the end of the tutorial and attempt to create the Tab Bar Controller between 2 Table View Controllers without disrupting the Navigation Area?

https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I simply had to uncheck the "Show Navigation Bar" for the initial Navigation Controller.